# filtering data in django rest framework with django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i want to select all data with the same item in Product table.

```
class ProductViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes  =(permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser)
        queryset = Generate.objects.all()
        serializer_class = GenerateSerializer
```

Here is my modelViewSet. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with django-filter

```
class ProductViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes  =(permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser)
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['desination']
```

Now you can do : http://localhost.com/api/products/?desination=exemple